# Avoid restarting jupyter notebook when encountering cuda out of memory exception?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am using pytorch and jupyter notebook. Frequently I'll encounter cuda out of memory and need to restart the notebook. How can I avoid needing to restart the whole notebook? I tried del a few variables but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Throw an exception in a new cell (ie 1/0)
2. Delete variables
3. Run `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`

The reason for `1` is when you have an error in a jupyter notebook, jupyter saves the error state to allow for use of the jupyter debugger. The error state holds references to GPU variables involved in the error, which prevents them from being cleared from memory. Throwing a new exception clears the old error state.